# javascript transform doesn't apply at all

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transform

Little introduction, so i've made an animated clock as homework just using CSS ans HTML but i want to learn a bit more so i've been searching for hour sync and i've decided to do it using JS,  tried this but don't know why it doesn't change the initial state, the animation just starts with the needles at 12h. position(it's original state):

```js
let seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
let hours = document.getElementById("hours");
let minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
let date = new Date();
let dateMinutes = date.getMinutes();
let dateSeconds = date.getSeconds();
let dateHours = date.getHours();
let currentHour = dateHours + date.getTimezoneOffset();
console.log(dateHours, dateMinutes, dateSeconds);
seconds.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
minutes.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
hours.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
if (currentHour > 12) {
  currentHour = currentHour / 2;
}
let percentHours = (360 / 43200) * (currentHour * 3600);
let percentMin = dateMinutes * 6;
let percentSec = dateSeconds * 6;
seconds.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + percentSec + "deg)";
minutes.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + percentMin + "deg)";
hours.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + percentHours + "deg)";
seconds.style.mozTransform = "rotateZ(" + percentSec + "deg)";
minutes.style.mozTransform = "rotateZ(" + percentMin + "deg)";
hours.style.mozTransform = "rotateZ(" + percentHours + "deg)";
seconds.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + percentSec + "deg)";
minutes.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + percentMin + "deg)";
hours.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + percentHours + "deg)";
seconds.style.animationPlayState = "running";
minutes.style.animationPlayState = "running";
hours.style.animationPlayState = "running";
```

```css
#clock {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 15px solid rgba(29, 29, 29, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(117, 141, 163, 0.37);
  background-image: url(clock2.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#seconds {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 180px;
  border-top: 2px solid #131111;
  border-left: 2px solid #131111;
  border-right: 2px solid #131111;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 28, 17);
  top: 20px;
  left: 197px;
  animation: rotarSeg 60s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: steps(60);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#minutes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 4px;
  height: 160px;
  right: 196px;
  border-top: 4px solid #131111;
  border-left: 2px solid #131111;
  border-right: 2px solid #131111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(246, 248, 248);
  margin-top: 38px;
  animation: rotarSeg 3600s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: steps(60);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#hours {
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 120px;
  top: 74px;
  left: 193px;
  border-top: 6px solid #131111;
  border-left: 4px solid #131111;
  border-right: 4px solid #131111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 246, 193, 0.705);
  animation: rotar 43200s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
```

when I excute the HTML file in server it doesn't work any ideas please?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'seconds' before initialization`

Comment: getElementById expects a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
let hours = document.getElementById("hours");
let minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
let date = new Date();
let dateMinutes = date.getMinutes();
let dateSeconds = date.getSeconds();
let dateHours = date.getHours();
let currentHour = dateHours + date.getTimezoneOffset();
console.log(dateHours, dateMinutes, dateSeconds);
seconds.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
minutes.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
hours.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
if (currentHour > 12) {
  currentHour = currentHour / 2;
}
let percentHours = (360 / 43200) * (currentHour * 3600);
let percentMin = dateMinutes * 6;
let percentSec = dateSeconds * 6;
seconds.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + percentSec + "deg)";
minutes.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + percentMin + "deg)";
hours.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + percentHours + "deg)";
seconds.style.mozTransform = "rotateZ(" + percentSec + "deg)";
minutes.style.mozTransform = "rotateZ(" + percentMin + "deg)";
hours.style.mozTransform = "rotateZ(" + percentHours + "deg)";
seconds.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + percentSec + "deg)";
minutes.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + percentMin + "deg)";
hours.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + percentHours + "deg)";
seconds.style.animationPlayState = "running";
minutes.style.animationPlayState = "running";
hours.style.animationPlayState = "running";
```

```css
#clock {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 15px solid rgba(29, 29, 29, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(117, 141, 163, 0.37);
  background-image: url(clock2.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#seconds {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 180px;
  border-top: 2px solid #131111;
  border-left: 2px solid #131111;
  border-right: 2px solid #131111;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 28, 17);
  top: 20px;
  left: 197px;
  animation: rotarSeg 60s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: steps(60);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#minutes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 4px;
  height: 160px;
  right: 196px;
  border-top: 4px solid #131111;
  border-left: 2px solid #131111;
  border-right: 2px solid #131111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(246, 248, 248);
  margin-top: 38px;
  animation: rotarSeg 3600s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: steps(60);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#hours {
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 120px;
  top: 74px;
  left: 193px;
  border-top: 6px solid #131111;
  border-left: 4px solid #131111;
  border-right: 4px solid #131111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 246, 193, 0.705);
  animation: rotar 43200s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
```

```html
<span id="hours"></span>
<span id="minutes"></span>
<span id="seconds"></span>
```

**To make it compile:**

The root of the issue is that `seconds` is not defined. Please see pointer to fix that in above code.

Added dummy HTML and fixes refence in first 3 lines of JS code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and letting me know i'm an idiot, i have to say that after fixing the obvious problem on first three lines the problem is still there i don't know why but there it is.
seconds.style.animationPlayState="paused"; in this sentence, seconds object, appear to be null

Comment: You are welcome! And no, you are not an idiot. Unless all of us - developers - are :) We all make mistakes and it helps us learn.